# wordpress Error establishing a database connection on repair.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the common error: `Error establishing a database connection`

So, I followed a few tutorials and have completed all suggestions with no success.

I have added: `define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );` to `wp-admin.php` and gone to localhost/wp-admin/maint/repair.php`but it looks just like`localhost`.

I have set DB_USER, DB_NAME, DB_HOST, and DB_PASSWORD to root, db_name, localhost, and my_password respectively, but the error persists. I have tried `mysql -u root -pmy_password` followed by `msql>use db_name` from the command line with success, so I know my credentials are good.

Is there some other way to check whats going wrong?

Comment: is this problem in local server or live server ????

Comment: @RaviSukhadia I am trying to run a server on a new local machine. There's a live server whose code I pulled and am trying to get familiar with it locally

Comment: can you set username : root and password : blank also set host name is localhost